# Pass selected values from one page table to another page table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Hi all,
>
> **Step 1:** I have a html home page which has 3 buttons(button1, button2 and button3) and a table with lets say 10 records.
>
> **Step 2:** User clicks(single click) to select 3 records out of 10 and click on button1
>
> **Step 3:** Then button1 html page should open with a table containing 3 records selected at step 2
>
> **Step 4:** Same steps to open button2 and button 3 home page
>
> Could you please suggest how to implement the same using jquery or
>   javascript or any other language?

Comment: There are MANY ways that this could be accomplished . . . what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I am new to jqery and javascript so dont know how to implement this. Pls suggest how can I implement it.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a simpler way to do this, but this works. Review the example, see how it works, and you should be able to continue your project from here.

First, the way to send data from Page1 to Page2 is to use a form and POST the data.

To do this, (1) loop through your checkboxes, (2) save the items to an array, (3) convert the array to JSON (i.e. text), (4) construct a form containing the stringified array, (5) append the form to the document, and (6) submit the form

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3yqko2m/1/)

**page1.html:**

```
var thejson, cars = [];
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    $('table tbody tr input:checked').each(function(idx,el){
        if ( this.checked ){
            //alert( $(el).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text() );
            //alert( idx );
            cars[idx] = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();
        }
    });
    //alert( cars.length );

    /* Note: replace " with | b/c the " will interfere with value="" */
    thejson = JSON.stringify(cars).replace(/"/g, '|');
    //alert( thejson );

    //Now, create a form and send it to your next page:
    var frm = '<form id="myForm" action="page2.html" method="post">';
    frm += '<input type="text" name="myJSON" value="'+thejson+'" />';
    frm += '</form>';
    $('body').append(frm);
    //$('#myForm').submit();  //NOTE -- ENABLE THIS WHEN READY
}); //END mybutt.click
```

**page2.html:**

```
<?php
    //Step1: receive the POSTed data
    $json = $_POST['myJSON']; //note: spelling and capitalization is CRITICAL
    $json = str_replace('|', '"', $json);  //turn it back into valid JSON
    $arr = json_decode($json);

    //Step 2: construct the HTML
    $out = '<div style="width:200px;padding:30px;background:lavender;border:1px solid blue;">';

    foreach ($car in $arr){
        $out .= 'Car: ' .$car. '<br>';
    }
    $out .= '</div>';

    //Step 3: display the HTML
    echo $out;
```

Notes:

(1) In `page1.html`, to save the json string into an input form, we replace the `"` with `|`. The reason for this is because `value="["car1","car2","car3"]"` is just gonna cause problems!  This won't cause problems: `value="[|car1|,|car2|,|car3|]"`

(2) In `page2.html`, you receive the POSTed json array, and use that data to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this example I have 6 checkboxes (instead of 10) and if one of these is checked I display that checkbox's value overwrite the form.

```
<form id="foo">
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="a" />a
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="b" />b
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="c" />c
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="d" />d
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="e" />e
    <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="f" />f
    <button onclick="myscript();">Button1</button>
</form>

<script>
    function myscript()
    {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('box');
        var selectedelements = "";
        for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
        {
            if(checkboxes[i].checked)
            {
                selectedelements = selectedelements + checkboxes[i].value;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = selectedelements;
    }
</script>
```